# Sort by nested field

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I've a type in elastic with documents with this structure

```
{
  "name": "Foo Bar",
  "myTags": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "My tag 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "My Tag 5"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "My Tag 7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, given 3 tags I would like to get ALL documents sorted by the number of matching tags. So first the documents that match all 3 tags than those that match 2 then one and finally none.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You use scoring for this and use a `bool` with three (3 tags) `should` statements that will increase the scoring if one tag "matches" (whatever that means in your use case). The idea is that if one tag matches it will increase the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `function_score`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }, 
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "myTags",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "myTags.name": "My Tag 1"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "myTags",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "myTags.name": "My Tag 5"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "myTags",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "myTags.name": "My Tag 7"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "sum", 
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on Elastic 1.7.5. Is this query ok ?

Comment: It should work with 1.7. The idea is that if a document matches one of the tags the score gets a +1. If it's matching another tag, then another +1 and so on. Basically, the final score will be the count of matching tags +1 (from the default `match_all` default query).

Comment: I had to change `weight : 1` to `weight : 2` otherwise I was getting strange/wrong result when filtering only with one tag.